# How to transmit hex code via IR blaster in Android?

Tags: android, infrared

I got all the signal of my tv remote in hex format(eg "38863BD2" for power on and off). The codes are in NEC format. Now I want to transmit all these code via my phone's IR blaster. I have buttons for every action in my activity. I want to transmit different hex code on different button click!
Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: I don't think there's an official API for IR blaster. I think you should look for especial APIs provided by the device manufacturers.

Comment: how does universal remote applications work then?